# How to get latitude and longitude in Google Auto complete locations

Tags: ios7.1

Im getting user location address using google Auto completion.

after user type a text in the search bar relavent addresses are drop down in a table, when I click on one address its getting that address like this.

under

 `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

I have done like this

`

```
 SPGooglePlacesAutocompletePlace *place = [self placeAtIndexPath:indexPath];
 [place resolveToPlacemark:^(CLPlacemark *placemark, NSString *addressString, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        SPPresentAlertViewWithErrorAndTitle(error, @"Could not map selected Place");
    } else if (placemark) {
        [self addPlacemarkAnnotationToMap:placemark addressString:addressString];
        [self recenterMapToPlacemark:placemark];
        [self dismissSearchControllerWhileStayingActive];
        [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

        NSLog(@"Address %@",addressString);
```

`

Now I want to get the latitude and longitude of theselected address. How can I get those. Please help me.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

NSLog(@"Address %@, %lf, %lf",addressString, placemark.location.coordinate.latitude, placemark.location.coordinate.longitude); XD